# Social "tact" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How does one say "tact" in Latin?

[*OED*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/196957#eid19135214):

> 2. Ready and delicate sense of what is fitting and proper in dealing with others, so as to avoid giving offence, or win good will; skill or judgement in dealing with men or negotiating difficult or delicate situations; the faculty of saying or doing the right thing at the right time.  [ < French *[tact](https://artflsrv03.uchicago.edu/philologic4/publicdicos/query?report=bibliography&filename=Littre.*&head=tact)* (Voltaire 1769).]

*Dexteritas*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a handful of words in classical Latin that denote skill in handling social situations: urbanitas, humanitas, comitas, facilitas.

*Facilitas* in particular might be ideal for representing being at ease in or having an easy-going manner in a given situation. However, it has a rather wide semantic field. Therefore, to specify it as a social grace, ancient authors often paired it with another word that is more recognizably social in nature. In Cicero we find in one instance *comitatem et facilitatem*, and in another *facilitate et humanitate*.

Also, *lenitas* denotes a gentle manner that might be considered tactful as opposed to forceful.

*Dexteritas* is a rather uncommon word, but Livy does use *ingenii dexteritas* parallel to *comitas* in describing Scipio. The meaning there seems to be that he was a very quick-witted or highly adaptable.

Answer (score 4):

Bona venia M. Tullii Ciceronis (qui vix illam veniam mihi negare potest) proponam: "Tact" est **facultas sentiendi quid deceat, et in factis dictisque qui sit modus.**

Nam ille scripsit ([De officiis, 1,14](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/off1.shtml#14)):

> Nec vero illa parva vis naturae est rationisque, quod unum hoc animal sentit, quid sit ordo, quid sit quod deceat, in factis dictisque qui modus.